# How to idiomatically require a trait to retrieve a slice

Tags: rust, type-conversion, traits

I'm working on [a library that operates on `[T]` slices](https://github.com/dropbox/rust-alloc-no-stdlib/blob/master/src/allocated_memory/mod.rs). I would like the library user to specify a type that can retrieve a slice in a mutable or immutable way.

My current lib defines 2 traits

```
pub trait SliceWrapper<T> {
    fn slice(&self) -> &[T];
}
pub trait SliceWrapperMut<T> {
    fn slice_mut (&mut self) -> &mut [T];
}
```

But the names `slice` and `slice_mut` seem arbitrary and not somewhere in the core Rust libs.

Is there a trait I should be requiring instead, like `Into::<&mut [T]>` ?

I'm afraid that `Into` consumes the type rather than just referencing it, so I can't simply demand the caller type implements `core::convert::Into`, can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to answer this is to look at the documentation for existing types that more or less do what you want.  This sounds like something `Vec` would do, so why not look at the [documentation for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)?

If you search through it looking for `-> &`, you'll find numerous methods that return borrowed slices:

- [`Vec::as_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice)
- [`Borrow::borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#tymethod.borrow)
- [`Index::<Range<usize>>::index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) (plus for `RangeTo<usize>`, `RangeFrom<usize>`, `RangeFull`, `RangeInclusive<usize>`, and `RangeToInclusive<usize>`)
- [`Deref::deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#tymethod.deref)
- [`AsRef::<[T]>::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref)

Which of these should you implement?  I don't know; which ones make sense?  Read the documentation on each method (and the associated trait) and see if what it describes is what you want to permit.  You say "that can retrieve a slice", but you don't really explain what that means.  A big part of traits is not just abstracting out common interfaces, but giving those interfaces meaning beyond what the code strictly allows.

If the methods listed aren't right; if none of them *quite* convey the correct semantics, then make a new trait.  Don't feel compelled to implement a trait just because you technically *can*.

As for `Into`, again, *read the documentation*:

> A conversion that **consumes `self`**, which may or may not be expensive.

Emphasis mine.  Implementing `Into` in this context makes no sense: if you consume the value, you can't borrow from it.  Oh, also:

> Library authors should not directly implement this trait, but should prefer implementing the `From` trait, which offers greater flexibility and provides an equivalent `Into` implementation for free, thanks to a blanket implementation in the standard library.

So yeah, I wouldn't use `Into` for this.  Or `From`.

Comment: This looks like what I need! Thanks
AsRef::<[T]>::as_ref